# how do I convert 60000 cells in to text by adding a single quote?

Tags: microsoft-excel

want to convert

> 311562 = '311562

i tried using this formula `=CONCATENATE("'",B8)` and then i copied the result to notepad

> '311562

and then pasted the result again into excel, but it is not working excel automatically changes the 
 out put to 2 single quotes

> ''311562

Edit:

if i use char(39), POI API is adding the quote in the data i don't want that.
[image: using Char(7)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use Flash Fill.

If your data is in column A, give an example of converted data in column B; i.e. if 311562 is in A1, write '311562 in B1.

[image: Like This:]

Now, press CTRL+E or click on Home->Fill->Flash Fill.

Comment: amazing, much easier then before.

Answer (score 1):

With values in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=CHAR(39) & A1
```

and copy downwards.  Then copy column **B** and PasteSpecialValues back onto column **A**.

**EDIT#1:**

The best you can do is to run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub ApplyTick()
    For Each r In Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(2)
        r.Value = "'" & r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

This code applies a `PrefixCharacter` to each constant in column **A**.

**EDIT#2:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: used you method kind of worked but now single quote is now appearing in the data.

Comment: @vaibhavcool20 Do you want the single quote to be visible only in the *Formula Bar*

Comment: no i don't want it visible. i want it hidden.

Comment: @vaibhavcool20  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: sorry for being a n00b but can you suggest how can execute this script?

Comment: @vaibhavcool20 We are all n00bs.............see my **EDIT#2**

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a different approach here.

Make a selection of the cells you want to change, then right-click the selection and choose `Format Cells`. Change the Cell formatting from Default to Text.

Excel will now understand that these numbers are text, and will align them to the left and treat them as text, not numbers. It has the exact same effect as to when you add a ' in front of the number, except, you can also change it back if you want, which I think is a bonus.

Comment: thanks for posting, this method is not working with poi api.

Comment: You don't add a char in front at all, just changing the cell properties. This also makes it so that you can copy/paste without having that char either. Or am I misunderstanding you now?

Comment: changing the cell properties does not work because i want to read data through java use the library called POI API, the limitation of that library is that it cannot read cell properties, it only works with text if there is a single quote in front.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That part was originally not in your question.